# How to wrap images in a div in the_content();?

Tags: wordpress

So then you add media to a post in the wordpress theme, such as images,
it always goes this way:

```
<img src="http://localhost:8888/example/wp-content/uploads/example.jpg" alt="leaf graphic" title="leaf graphic" class="alignright size-medium wp-image-3109" height="25" width="30"/>
```

But my goal is to wrap any image which i add to a post in a div, like this:

```
<div class="card">
<img class="img-fluid" src="http://localhost:8888/example/wp-content/uploads/example.jpg" alt="" />
</div>
```

Are there any ways to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use *media_send_to_editor* filter for that.
When you insert any media to your editor, it goes through that filter.

```
add_filter('media_send_to_editor', 'inserted_image_div', 10, 3 );

function inserted_image_div( $html, $send_id, $attachment )
{
    return '<div class="card">'.$html.'</div>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't work if you're trying to wrap an image with a caption since WordPress uses a shortcode when outputting the image and caption to screen. It seems to disregard the `media_send_to_editor` filter altogether in this scenario.

To wrap an an image with a caption you'll need to edit the output of the shortcode.

```
add_filter( 'img_caption_shortcode', 'my_img_caption_shortcode', 10, 3 );

function my_img_caption_shortcode( $empty, $attr, $content ){
    $attr = shortcode_atts( array(
        'id'      => '',
        'align'   => 'alignnone',
        'width'   => '',
        'caption' => ''
    ), $attr );

    if ( 1 > (int) $attr['width'] || empty( $attr['caption'] ) ) {
        return '';
    }

    if ( $attr['id'] ) {
        $attr['id'] = 'id="' . esc_attr( $attr['id'] ) . '" ';
    }

    return '<div ' . $attr['id']
    . 'class="wp-caption ' . esc_attr( $attr['align'] ) . '" '
    . 'style="max-width: ' . ( 10 + (int) $attr['width'] ) . 'px;">'
    . '<div class="CLASS-NAME-HERE">' . do_shortcode( $content ) . '</div>'
    . '<p class="wp-caption-text">' . $attr['caption'] . '</p>'
    . '</div>';

}
```

`do_shortcode($content)` outputs the image, so this line is where you'd add the wrapping div or other container:

```
'<div class="CLASS-NAME-HERE">' . do_shortcode( $content ) . '</div>'
```

See https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/img_caption_shortcode